# Update/Save Button (Java DB)

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a button that updates the records in my Java DB, but whenever I click the button I keep getting this error, "Invalid operation at current cursor position". I can't figure out the problem, so maybe someone can help me? I've already made a shorter version of this work, but I can't make this one work. Some help would be much appreciated.

```
  i = Integer.parseInt(txt_userid.getText( ));
  s = txt_pass.getText( );
  n = txt_name.getText( );
  birthdate = txt_bdate.getText( );
  contactno = Integer.parseInt(txt_contact.getText( ));
  age = Integer.parseInt(txt_age.getText( ));
  email = txt_email.getText( );
  address = txt_address.getText( );
  gender = txt_gender.getText( );
  adult = Integer.parseInt(txt_adult.getText( ));
  children = Integer.parseInt(txt_child.getText( ));
  seniors = Integer.parseInt(txt_senior.getText( ));
  charge = Integer.parseInt(txt_charge.getText( ));
  travelclass = txt_travelclass.getText( );
  luggage = txt_luggage.getText( );
  flightID = txt_flightid.getText( );
  departdate = txt_depardate.getText( );
  departtime = txt_departime.getText( );
  destination = txt_destination.getText( );
  arrivdate = txt_arrivdate.getText( );
  arrivtime = txt_arrivtime.getText( );

  try{

      rs.updateInt("USERID",i);
      rs.updateString("PASSWORD",s);
      rs.updateString("USERNAME",n);
      rs.updateInt("AGE",age);
      rs.updateString("GENDER",gender);
      rs.updateString("BIRTHDATE",birthdate);
      rs.updateString("EMAIL",email);
      rs.updateInt("CONTACTNO",contactno);
      rs.updateString("ADDRESS",address);
      rs.updateString("FLIGHTID", flightID);
      rs.updateString("DEPARDATE", departdate);
      rs.updateString("DEPARTIME", departtime);
      rs.updateString("DESTINATION", destination);
      rs.updateString("TRAVELCLASS", travelclass);
      rs.updateString("LUGGAGE", luggage);
      rs.updateInt("TOTALPAY", charge);
      rs.updateInt("ADDPASSENGERSSENIOR", seniors);
      rs.updateInt("ADDPASSENGERSADULT", adult);
      rs.updateInt("ADDPASSENGERSCHILD", children);
      rs.updateString("ARRIVALDATE", arrivdate);
      rs.updateString("ARRIVALTIME", arrivtime);
      rs.updateRow( );
      Refresh_RS_STMT();
      ShowAll();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(AdminWindow.this,
              "Record has been saved!");
  }catch(SQLException err){
      System.out.println(err.getMessage() );

  }
```

Error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.updateInt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.updateInt(Unknown Source)
at airline_system.AdminWindow.btn_saveActionPerformed(AdminWindow.java:719)
at airline_system.AdminWindow.access$600(AdminWindow.java:5)
at airline_system.AdminWindow$7.actionPerformed(AdminWindow.java:344)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ERROR XJ121: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
at     org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.checkUpdatePreconditions(Unknown Source)
... 41 more
```

Comment: From where is `rs` coming from?

Comment: use `err.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(err.getMessage() );`. you want as much info as possible when debugging, not to make it look nice for the user

Comment: What do you mean where is `rs` coming from? I'm still a bit new to using the database. If you mean where the `ResultSet rs` is declared, then I'm using inheritance to extend it from a class file.

Comment: I edited the OP with the error message from the `err.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Please include the code before the first line you are currently showing.  It looks like your problem is caused by something from before the code you have shown starts.